# Flutter: Using a Builder method as a way to declare variables inside a widget

Tags: flutter

Consider the following widget:

```html
class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool condition1 = true;

    return Column(
      children: [
        // inserting widget1 based on condition1
        if (condition1) ...[
          Builder(
            // creating a Builder widget in order to decalre 'condition2'
            builder: (context) {
              bool condition2 = true; // just an example, not actual value
              return condition2 ? const MyWidget2() : const MyWidget3();
            },
          )
        ]
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to display different widgets based on conditions. I wrap the widgets inside a Builder since I want to be able to declare the variables inside the nested widget (No, they can't be declared higher up in the widget tree).

**The question is**, whether this is the right way to do that? Because what if you have a BlocBuilder for example, and you listen for a certain state of 'success', **BUT** within than state you could either show the items or something else? I can't think of another way to declare variables in such a scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's totally fine with your idea. If you want your code to be clearer, you can create a new widget and put the condition in the in the build method.
For example

```
class ConditionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool condition2 = true;
    return condition2 ? const MyWidget2() : const MyWidget3();
  }
```

and then in the MainWidget

```
class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool condition1 = true;

    return Column(
      children: [
        // inserting widget1 based on condition1
        if (condition1) ...[
          ConditionWidget()
        ]
      ],
    );
  }
}
```